# Handle dependencies in Go

Tags: go, dependency-management

In Go, if you reference another package, e.g. something on GitHub, then Go always gets the latest version from the `master` branch. While this is great for development, I guess it's a problem in production: This way a build is not reproducible.

So, what is the correct way in Go to fix a version of a dependency, and how to handle this efficiently?

A friend pointed me to [godep](http://godoc.org/github.com/tools/godep), and this seems fine, but I wanted to know what alternatives are there, and what's good / bad about godep?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update 2018 with Go 1.11

[Dependencies should now be referenced with modules](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#modules) (derived from [the vgo project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914523/6309)):

> Go 1.11 adds preliminary support for a new concept called “modules,” an alternative to `GOPATH` with integrated support for versioning and package distribution.
>   Using modules, developers are no longer confined to working inside `GOPATH`, version dependency information is explicit yet lightweight, and builds are more reliable and reproducible.

See **[Defining a module](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Defining_a_module)**. (and the [original design proposal](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/2c6bc83f234085c8eadb7ea33405ce6223c44d1b/design/24301-versioned-go.md))

---

Update June 2015: first support for vendoring is making its way in Go 1.5!
See [c/10923/](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/10923/):

> When `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` is in the environment, this CL changes the resolution of import paths according to the Go 1.5 vendor proposal:
>
> - If there is a source directory `d/vendor`, then, when compiling a source file within the subtree rooted at `d`, `import "p"` is interpreted as `import "d/vendor/p"` if that exists.
> - When there are multiple possible resolutions, the most specific (longest) path wins.
> - The short form must always be used: no import path can contain “`/vendor/`” explicitly.
> - Import comments are ignored in vendored packages.

---

Update March 2015: the go team is thinking about defining a go dependency management system integrated to the language: the debate is **[in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-dev/nMWoEAG55v8)**.

> We think it’s time to start addressing the dependency & vendoring issue, especially before too many conflicting tools arise and fragment best practices in the Go ecosystem, unnecessarily complicating tooling. It would be nice if the community could converge on a standard way to vendor.
>
> Our proposal is that the Go project,
>
> 1. officially recommends vendoring into an “[internal](https://docs.google.com/a/golang.org/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit)” directory with import rewriting (not `GOPATH` modifications) as the canonical way to pin dependencies.
> 2. defines a common config file format for dependencies & vendoring
> 3. makes no code changes to `cmd/go` in Go 1.5. External tools such as “`godep`” or “`nut`” will implement 1) and 2). We can reevaluate including such a tool in Go 1.6+.

---

One possible downside of [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) is that you can no longer use "go build" or "go test" directly.
You need to precede those commands with `godep` (or type `godep save`).

An alternative is [**glide**](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), which remains compatible with classic go commands.

> - Manage project-specific GOPATHs
> - Ease dependency management
> - Support versioning packages
> - Support aliasing packages (e.g. for working with github forks)
> - Remove the need for "vendoring" or munging import statements
> - Work with all of the go tools

---

More generally, the article "[Know your guarantees, Go edition](http://clipperhouse.com/2014/07/11/know-your-guarantees-go-edition/)" is interesting:

> It’s also a deliberate choice, where the Go authors chose not to implement a feature when they felt that the trade-offs were no good.
>
> One low-level reason they made this choice is to avoid slow compilation and bloated binaries (which are two sides of the same coin).
>   Remember, **packages depend on other packages**. So `Foo` might depend on `Bar` 2.1. `Foo` might also depend on `Baz` which in turn depends on `Bar` 1.9, and on down the tree. So that would mean compiling and linking several copies of nearly identical code.
>
> Depending on several versions of the same package also means knowing which version one is calling, whereby the dependency mess seeps into your source code.
>
> Which leads us to the high-level reasoning behind the Go platform punting on this feature: **they did not have a logical solution they considered acceptable. It’s not that they don’t understand the problem; it’s that, at the moment, there is not a solution they like. So they choose no feature over over a regressive one**.

Answer (score 1):

You handle dependencies like you do handle dependencies in other languages too: You vendor.  For Go there is no Nexus which does the vendoring so most just copy external libraries into a "vendor" folder, there are tools helping here. Personally I found all this "fix version" panic a bit exaggerated as it works pretty well without.

You might wanna take a look at http://labix.org/gopkg.in and search golang-nuts for dependency management.  I think there is even a whole mailing list devoted to this.