# Why Go put all code in $GOPATH/src

Tags: go

When I make a package use `go install`, I found Go search the package form two path

1. `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/src/` go install dir. many base package like fmt...
2. `/Users/godtail/Product/go/go_path/src/` $GOPATH/src. bad $GOPATH, I will change it.

also can use relative path, but is not recommended.

I always put my work dir like this.

```
Product A
    php
    nodejs
    go(i hope to put here)
Product B
    java
    nodejs
...
```

How can I do like this? or maybe change dir follow Go.
Give me some advice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages

> Go programs are constructed by linking together packages. A package in
>   turn is constructed from one or more source files that together
>   declare constants, types, variables and functions belonging to the
>   package and which are accessible in all files of the same package.
>   Those elements may be exported and used in another package.
>
> Source file organization
>
> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to
>   which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import
>   declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use,
>   followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types,
>   variables, and constants.
>
> SourceFile       = PackageClause ";" { ImportDecl ";" } { TopLevelDecl
>   ";" } .

You may add many `src` dirs to your `$GOPATH`:

> Like the system PATH environment variable, Go path is a `:` delimited 
>    list of directories where Go will look for packages (`;`on Windows).

So you may add your project `src` dir to the `$GOPATH`.
Or just store your library packages in one `$GOPATH`.

Comment: Thank your for answer ~.i should move my library packages to the $GOPATH dir. also can improve reuse. and when i use git how can i push my lib package. or i have some product use the same lib package.

Comment: did go have package manger like composer or npm ? then i just need to edit the config json. and it can pull code from remote.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300279/golang-dependency-management-best-practice

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. Golang is going to introduce an official tool called `dep`, which is like `pip` for python or `npm` for node.js.

Comment: is this still valid?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch No, use go mod instead.