# Setting `GOPATH` for each vscode project

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Setting the `GOPATH` variable global as an enviroment variable works fine with Visual Studio Code.

But setting a project specific variable globally doesn't seem very nice to me. Consider you have multiple `Go` projects, you would have to change this variable each time you, compile, debug, ... etc. a project.

Is there a possibility to set the `GOPATH` variable as a project variable in Visual Studio Code? Ether in `settings.json` or `launch.json`?

Comment: don't try to change `GOPATH` for each project, [use `vendor` folder](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/vendor-folder/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go 1.5 added the vendor directory that allows a per-project dependency management.

> If there is a source directory d/vendor, then, when compiling a source file within the subtree rooted at d, import "p" is interpreted as import "d/vendor/p" if that path names a directory containing at least one file with a name ending in “.go”.

[source](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bz5-UB7g2uPBdOx-rw5t9MxJwkfpx90cqG9AFL0JAYo/edit)

This feature has been enabled by default with Go 1.6:

> Go 1.5 introduced experimental support for a “vendor” directory that was enabled by an environment variable. In Go 1.6, the feature is now enabled by default.

[source](https://blog.golang.org/go1.6)

Even with the 1.6 version, depending on the tools you use, you might need to set the `GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT` environment variable to `1` (`export GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1` on unix-based OS)

Answer (score 17):

(Q2 2018:
Note that with the [vgo project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914523/6309), `GOPATH` might end up being deprecated in favor of a project-based workflow. That would avoid the manual project-based `GOPATH` I was proposing below, two years ago)

With Go 1.11 (August 2018), [`GOPATH` can be optional, with **modules**](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#modules).

It is more and more supported with VSCode:

- [vscode-go/issue 1532](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/1532#issuecomment-424906159)
- "[Go modules support in Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-modules-support-in-Visual-Studio-Code)"

---

In addition to vendor folder, you still can have one `GOPATH` per project.

See "[`GOPATH` from `go.inferGopath` setting](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension#gopath-from-goinfergopath-setting)":

> ### `GOPATH` from `go.inferGopath` setting
>
> Setting `go.inferGopath` overrides all of the above.
>   If `go.inferGopath` is set to `true`, the extension will try to infer the `GOPATH` from the path of the workspace i.e. the directory opened in vscode. It searches upwards in the path for the `src` directory, and sets `GOPATH` to one level above that.
>
> For example, if your project looks like `/aaa/bbb/ccc/src/...`, then opening the directory `/aaa/bbb/ccc/src` (or anything below that) will cause the extension to search upwards, find the `src` component in the path, and set the `GOPATH` to one level above that i.e. `GOPATH=/aaa/bbb/ccc`.
>
> This setting is useful when you are working on different Go projects which have different `GOPATH`s. Instead of setting the `GOPATH` in the workspace settings of each project or setting all the paths as `;/:` separated string, you can just set `go.inferGopath` to `true` and the extension uses the right `GOPATH` automatically.
>
> ### `GOPATH` for installing the Go tools using `go.toolsGopath`
>
> By default, all the dependent Go tools are used from the `GOPATH` derived from the above logic.
>   If they are available on your `PATH`, the `PATH` is used to locate the Go tools.
>   If the Go tools are not in your path, you might end up with the same Go tools installed in each of your `GOPATH`s.
>   To prevent the Go tools from cluttering your `GOPATH`, use the `go.toolsGopath` setting to provide a separate location for the Go tools.
>
> The first time you set go.toolsGopath, you will have to run `Go: Install Tools` command so that the Go tools get installed in the provided location.

Comment: `inferGopath` with `toolsGopath` is great. Thx

Comment: @merito Indeed, but note that all that is obolete with Go modules now (1.11+): https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

The GOPATH is your workspace and it's divided in

```
GOPATH/
    |- bin/
    |- pkg/
    |- src/ <--- your projects are saved here
        |- .../my_project1
        |- .../my_project2
```

With this separation, your don't need to set a new GOPATH for each project. I recommend you read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: This is not very sufficient when you have a solution with different projects of different languages.

Comment: What do you mean with different languages? GOPATH is only your workspace for yours golang projects. If you're using other languages, they're not affected by GOPATH env variable. If you're taking about versioning, the vendor directory is your solution.

Comment: Consider you are writing applications of many microservices each and in each one of them is written in `Go` the others in `C++`, `JavaScript`, whatever... . Then your workspace tree looks strange...

Comment: helpful answer. this is kinda dumb design tho, it assumes you want all your `go` code in only one directory: `$GOPATH/src`, but what if I want more than one `$GOPATH/src` folder on my machine?

Answer (score 7):

set `workspace settings`, in windows:

1. goto settings: `ctrl+,`
2. set workspace setting:

   ```
   { 
        "go.gopath": "d:\\gopath;E:\\src"
   }
   ```

use `;` for multiple path

3. restart visual studio code to take effect.

Comment: This is correct to setup the default GOPATH for VS Code. As in my case I had a different GOPATH while VSCODE was still pointing to the old GOPATH. Thus, I added this config and `“go.toolsGopath”: “/Users/user/go/”` to tell VS Code to install tools in correct GOPATH. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

If your VSCode project directory is organized,

1. go to Settings
2. either search "Infer Gopath" or find this entry under Extensions/Go
3. check the box

Then VSCode infers GOPATH from your workspace root, which solves my problem immediately. I believe this is explained in other answers. I am posting this just to give a shorter version.