# Pushing a whole golang package to github

Tags: go

I have built a small application locally in golang.
My directory structure is as follows.

```
gocode/
      src/
          github.com/
                    travel/
                          config/
                          server/
                          routes/
                          main.go

      pkg/
          linux/
               github.com/
                    // projects with .a extension 
               golang.org/
                         x/net/
                         x/oauth2
      bin/
```

I went through a lot of documentations, which states to push only /src folder to github as best practice.

I am confused with what happens with packages like golang.org/x/net which are not inside /src directory.

So we need to run go import "net/http" in production server as well and create executable binaries.

I've come from a nodejs background so is it something like we do "npm install" in nodejs.But the thing is we have a package.json file in case of node.
Anyways please help me with this confusion.

Comment: What you're looking for is dependency management. Check out go dep, glide, and govendor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Dependency Management Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300279/golang-dependency-management-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only push the contents of the `src/github.com/travel` directory. `go get` handles dependency resolution for you when someone wants to download your package. Take a look at something like [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus). Running `go get github.com/sirupsen/logrus` will download all dependencies needed to build the package. This includes any of your `golang.org/x/` packages.

Comment: So after cloning from github we simply run a go get -v ./...  and get all the dependencies installed then we create binaries is that the way.

Comment: Should be, yeah.